# Where is the implementation of Convolution of tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

How Tensorflow implements its convolution operations? I know it's based on Eigen library and I trace it to `LaunchGeneric.launch` in /tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc, but where it goes? My guess is in /third_party_eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/NeuralNetworks/SpatialConvolutions.h, but I checked the BUILD file under eigen3 and it seems that file is not included to compile the library.

Answer (score 1):

The GPU implementation is just cuDNN. I think you're right on the CPU implementation, and it's included in the build from [eigen's BUILD file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/third_party/eigen.BUILD) via `"Eigen/**"` (recursive wildcard).